# Picasso image not displaying android

Tags: android, json, node.js

on my nodeJS server, i have an image that is displaying on web app however it can not be accesses from the android app using Picasso.

the url from the server is :

```
https://www.mesannuairesvideos.com/uploads/file-1491574016406.jpg
```

my code is :

```
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("https://www.mesannuairesvideos.com/uploads/file-1491574016406.jpg")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.real_madrid_tshirt)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                    .resize(250, 200)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(imageView);
```

could anyone try to open it in an android test app please, I want to see if it can be included in an imageView on android application

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: What is happening in your CircleTransform class (can you provide the code)?

Comment: I recommend the use of Glide. Better performance :)

Comment: did you add the <INTERNET> permission and add `.setLoggingEnabled(true);` to see any error log

Comment: First, add the rest of the code and layout where you declare your imageview. Besides, divide and conquer, first try removing all "not mandatory" attributes for loading the image. Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("https://www.mesannuairesvideos.com/uploads/file-1491574016406.jpg")
                    .into(imageView);

Comment: @inner_class7 it's not about the picasso , all work fine with it, the issue is that the image won't be shown in android application

Comment: @rafsanahmad007  yes already done

Comment: @Jonathan Aste problem is not about the picasso cuz I tried many other urls and it works like a charm

Comment: please could anyone try to implement the url of the image into an imageView of a test android application, that would be so helpful , cuz I want to make sure that it doesn't work on an android application , image is clearly shown on any browser, it's weird !

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was having this issue and when I tried it on an actual device it was visible when it was not visible on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

your image cant be opened in browser neither maybe its your api-key or link